# Autohotkey Mouse Coordinates

Tags: coordinates, autohotkey

I recorded a whole bunch of user interactions using autohotkey.When I play the script back, my mouse coordinates which are supposed to click somewhere, click somewhere else instead. These mouse coordinates are relative to the active window so they shouldnt be clicking in the wrong places. Has anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a different Mouse [CoordMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)?  Try each of the following at the top of your script to see which works:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative  ;sets coordinates based upon active window

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen    ;sets coordinates based upon screen resolution
```

Comment: can you please give example about click relative to screen resolution, because I'm not able to find any working example.